# Is it correct to index all columns in a mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

My site is taking too long to load the contents and the CPU load used by mysql service reaches sometimes 200%. Checking the tables realized that the tables all columns were used as index. This is correct? It can affect performance?

My server configuration: 16GB RAM, 3.4GHz
Most tables have about 25k ~ 50k lines. And 10~20 Columns.

[All tables indexing are like this example. All columns as indexes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkUlX.png)

Comment: That cannot be considered a large database in fact I would call it tiny.

Comment: Unnecessary indexes are a waste of resources. But determining which indexes are most appropriate really depends on the actual queries that are being executed, and the performance expectations for those queries. Performance tuning is about a lot more than "indexes". All of the indexes on that table might be appropriate. From the information provided, we can't tell the difference between "*a careful analysis revealed that this particular set of indexes was most appropriate*", and the "*i just create an index on every column now because a long time i got burned by not having the right index*"

Comment: give someone (not me) 50 bucks to sort it out for you

Comment: I made a correction. But should i remove those unnecessary indexes?

Comment: Only remove the indexes if you determine they are unnecessary. The removal of indexes is unlikely to solve a performance problem. It is much more likely that the performance problem is due to the design of the queries, or the design of the database interactions (lots of calls in a tight loop), or connection churning. And we can't rule out lock contention (especially if there's DML running against MyISAM tables), an insufficiently sized buffer pool (for InnoDB). It's very unlikely that removing an index or two is going to solve a performance problem.

Answer (score 9):

No, you don't index all columns. You index columns that are specifically involved in a `WHERE` clause, and sometimes if they're involved in an `ORDER BY`.

In this case you'd want an index on `type`:

```
SELECT name FROM users WHERE type='admin'
```

In this case you'd want an index on `active,type`:

```
SELECT name FROM users WHERE type='admin' AND active=1
```

In this case you might want an index on `active,type,name`:

```
SELECT name FROM users WHERE type-='admin' AND active=1 ORDER BY name LIMIT 10
```

The more indexes you add the slower writes will be but the faster reads will be. This is a classic trade-off. Evaluate carefully what indexes you need and apply them only if there will be a tangible benefit. Don't just slap them on because you feel like they should be there.

On super tiny tables, those with <1000 rows, indexes won't help that much because a table scan won't take that long. On anything non-trivial they're absolutely essential.

If you're having performance problems I'd suggest that your schema is the biggest obstacle, not the lack of indexes.

Comment: ... plus foreign keys, and columns in a join predicate, and sometimes a GROUP BY can be satisfied using an index ("Using index for group by" in the EXPLAIN output).  And for some queries, a "covering index" is more beneficial than other indexes. +10.  Also important to consider on a busy system is contention for locks. (Choice of storage engine can have a performance impact.)

Comment: @spencer7593 All valid concerns, but these are the most basic instances. The exhaustive list of why you'd add an index is quite long as you point out.

Comment: I concur. Only in a very rare, exceptional circumstance would the most appropriate set of indexes be a singleton index on every column in a table. That set of indexes on the OP table does seem to be the result of a knee-jerk reaction... "*i'll add an index on every column because i got burned when i didn't have any indexes*". (That's partially understandable, when the creation of an appropriate index looks like a night-and-day "miracle cure" to a performance problem... that it would be taken to be the antidote to every performance problem.)

Comment: You should also pay attention to the order of the columns in the index. Indexes get chosen by the order the fields are used in the query

Comment: @BenCummins: Yes, the *order* of columns in an index is a *critical* part of the index definition. And it is about the statement, how the columns are referenced, in what clauses, what conditions, whether a particular index will be appropriate. Cardinality plays an important role too. (And just so we're clear... reordering conditions in statement, e.g. `WHERE t.a=1 AND t.b=2` *vs.* `WHERE t.b=2 AND t.a=1`, that doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 3):

No, you should not index all columns. It will be slower when you write data. It is not normal that your CPU reaches sometimes 200%. I suggest you check your SQL.

I'm sure optimizing SELECT statements is helpful.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/statement-optimization.html

1.Optimize your query with cache. Try to use parameter instead of functions.

(Thanks for @tadman's suggestion)

```
// no cache
$sql = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE signup_date >= CURDATE()";

// cache
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$sql = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE signup_date >= '$today'");
```

2.EXPLAIN you SELECT wisely. It helps you find potential performance issues.

```
EXPLAIN select name,phone from user where name="JakLiao";
```

3. Use "LIMIT N" when you only need first one row result.

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE country = 'China' limit 1;
```

4. Use index when you need it in where clause.

```
//row "name" should add index.
select * from user where name LIKE 'Jak%' limit 10;
```

5. Use index when you join tables.

```
select company_name FROM users LEFT JOIN companies ON (users.state = companies.state) WHERE users.id = 123;
```

6. Avoid "select *"

```
//not suggest
SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = 1;
//suggest
SELECT username FROM user WHERE user_id = 1;
```

7. PROCEDURE ANALYSE(), MYSQL will help you analysis your database and data.
8. COUNT(1) when you want to know rows of a table.

```
//not suggest
SELECT count(*) FROM user;
//suggest
SELECT count(1) FROM user;
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips. They was very helpfull. How about the MySQL variables? Like max connections, timeouts... Sometimes i got the error "Too many connections"

Comment: There are several good suggestions here. I might replace number 8. I'd recommend avoiding `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` when not needed.  The purported difference between `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(1)` is a myth. For number 1. the MySQL query cache can be a dangerous beast; there are lots of reasons beyond `NOW()` that query can't be cached. (In our shop, we have `query_cache_type=2` and include `SQL_CACHE` hint in the statements that we want cached.)

Comment: While the advice here is mostly reasonable, the use of the obsolete `mysql_query` function confuses this answer considerably. That function is dead, it's been deleted from PHP 7. Whenever possible try and give advice that's independent of the interface used, be that PDO or `mysqli` or an ORM of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

Indexing all columns is not correct. It affects performance of write operations. Each additional index requires additional time to update after write operation. Also each index costs additional space. You should index only the columns which will be used for searching.

Comment: ... also candidates for indexing are foreign keys, and columns used in join predicates, ORDER BY, GROUP BY, etc. (Some of those would not fall under the category of "only .. for searching".)