# Laravel query is very slow when i use 'join'. 30 million records

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I have got an big query that basically just adds a couple of with()'s, whereBetween() and orderBy. At the end i use a simplePaginate(500) because i don't want to call all 30mil records obviously.

Problem is that whenever i use a join than it will take couple minutes to load it, but when i dont use it than it only takes 2 seconds.

my query->join:

```
        $query
            ->join('balance_accounts', 'balances.balanceable_id','=', 'balance_accounts.id')
            ->join('currencies', 'currencies.id', "=", 'balance_accounts.currency_id')
            ->join('balance_types', 'balance_types.id', "=", 'balance_accounts.balance_type_id')
            ->select("balances.*", "currencies.short_name", "balance_types.name");
```

---

i have put indexes on every column. Maybe im putting indexes wrong because it's foreign, i have no idea..

here are my index that i have put on table 'balances':
[image]

here are my index that i have put on table 'balance_accounts':
[image]

here my index for 'currencies':
[image]

Comment: My first question would be, why do you want to get 30 million records at once?

Comment: @GertB. updated answer.

Comment: Please share more details, like the execution plan of that query. I would assume that you haven't added indexes for the relevant columns

Comment: @NicoHaase what do u mean with execution plan? what i want to do is filter data then paginate it and then send it to Vue in a api call.

Comment: Did you paginate the query or the collection?

Comment: @GertB. the query.

Comment: are you using eloquent queries or raw queries?

Comment: @RushikeshGanesh eloquent.

Comment: I think the more optimized the solution is to get chunks of data at a time using Query Builder its more convenient way to handle the data

Comment: @RushikeshGanesh yes that may be so. But then i still have to use join and orderby. and those 2 dont seem to work together quiet well as i explained.

Comment: instead of join use relations

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#chunking-results

Comment: @ChrisServ are you ordering by columns from joined tables? Or only from main table?

Comment: @Autista_z main table.

Comment: Then replace Joins with Eloquent relationships (multiple queries under the hood). Join operation is very resource expensive. With 30 milions records it will be very slow allways.  If you dont want to use cache, temporary tables, DB views or other workaround.

Comment: @Autista_z Ok so u recommended using DB instead eloquent. Even if i have 500 million records? which i actually have.. Or shouldn't i even be using Laravel for such big stuff...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59981047/how-to-execute-an-explain-select-on-a-laravel-builder for advice about how to get the execution plan of your query. That might help to inspect which indexes are missing

Comment: Also, having indexes on **all** columns is overkill and won't really help, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39987543/is-it-correct-to-index-all-columns-in-a-mysql-database/39987929 - after all, that will also negatively impact your performance!

Comment: @NicoHaase ok i will keep it in mind. but it has worked ok till now. i just wanted to understand why joins dont seem to be working with orderby but it does work with where/with/whereBetween

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Does the query return incorrect data? Or is this a pure performance issue (then keep in mind what a `JOIN` does, and how you could resolve this problem through inspecting the execution plan)

Comment: @ChrisServ If you order only by main table, and not by tables from joins, then instead of joins use Eloquent relationships: `$balances = Balance::with('account.currency', 'account.type')->whereBetween(...)->orderBy('column')->simplePaginate()`

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL; it will help us who are Laravel-challenged to help you.

Comment: Pagination is best done if you can "remember where you left off".  I think `simplePaginate` uses the inefficient `OFFSET`.

Comment: 3rd party packages often get in the way of using the full potential of the underlying database engine -- especially for 30M-row tables.